# attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: in Content Provider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am trying to insert some data into a `SQLite` table using a `ContentProvider`. No matter how I get the instance to `WritableDatabase` or `ReadableDataBase`, I always get `attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:`

Content Provider:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    helper = DBHelper.getInstance(getContext());
    Log.d(TAG,"OnCreate");
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
    return helper.getReadableDatabase()
            .query(DBConstants.TABLE_NAME, DBConstants.ALL_COLUMNS,
                    selection,null,null,null,
                    DBConstants.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP_ADDED + " DESC");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
    return null;
}
```

If I change the `onCreate()` method to:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    helper = DBHelper.getInstance(getContext());
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d(TAG,"OnCreate");
    return true;
}
```

I instantly get a illegalStateException with the same error when I call `database.getWritableDatabase()` in any of the methods in the class.

When searching in StackOverflow, I could find the issue due to calling `database.close()` method. But I am using `ContentProvider` to manage the database and not calling any `close()` method. So why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind.
In my DBHelper class, I was closing the database in `onCreate()` method. Commenting that line fixed the issue.